# What does this web.xml error mean?

Tags: schema, web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

> Referenced file contains errors (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd).  For  more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."

The errors below were detected when validating the file "web-app_2_5.xsd" via the file "web.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "web-app_2_5.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when web-app_2_5.xsd is validated in the context of web.xml.

In details, I see a bunch of these:

> s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than xs:appinfo and xs:documentation. Saw 'var _U="undefined";'

Comment: Sometimes it is a bug in Eclipse. Take a look how to disable the validation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271527/eclipse-language-servers-there-is-1-error-in-javaee-7-xsd

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you replace `j2ee` by `javaee`, it will work fine.

EDIT :

```
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

**Edit:**

To know anything further related to this error. Please follow the [Link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html). Here you will find schemas for Java EE deployment descriptors (web.xml).

Comment: wtf..this is annoying!

Comment: @jhohlfeld the list of schemas by release is currently here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html Schemas java <= 1.4 are use j2ee and schemas for >= 1.5 use javaee

Comment: I have this declaration and the error is still present

Comment: @Satzzadur Rahaman Can you explain why this is showing error?

Comment: In case it is not working as for @RonyeVernaes, check out this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538754/eclipse-web-xml-referenced-file-error

Comment: <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">                                                                                                          
   im getting errors for this

Answer (score 54):

replace

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

with

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

The solution is that you have to put semicolon between URLs

I am sure you will not get the error again :)

Comment: What is the reasoning to do this?  The error did go away, but I don't know what will be side effects

Comment: When I use this declaration, the validator says that "Cannot find the declaration of element'web-app'"

Comment: After adding a semicolon in my case (is a faces-config) the error (not on my mac eclipse only in my linux eclipse) went away but got a warning message: no grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you add `;` between 2 passages:
`xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee` and `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">`

Like this:

```
:xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Answer (score 9):

Add semicolon between **xsi:schemaLocation** just as shown below

> `"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"`

This resolved my this error in `<servlet-name>` tag line as well.

"cvc-id.3: A field of identity constraint 'web-common-servlet-name-uniqueness' matched element 'web-app', but this element does not have a simple type."

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had replaced

> xsi:schemaLocation="**http://java.sun.com**/../.."

with

> xsi:schemaLocation="**http://xmlns.jcp.org**/../.."

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

On the surface it appears that the schemaLocation is wrong. Resolving it appears to redirect to a HTML page rather than a XSD schema.

I would suggest simply removing this line unless you really want to do XSD validation at runtime. Bear in mind the relevant parts will be validated by your servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the schemaLocation as below has resovled the error for me:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/j2ee; http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case my solution is helpful for anyone. My problem was similar (same error although for a different XSD) and I have posted my solution to this also similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78053918/2467349.