# Eclipse Language Servers: There is '1' error in 'javaee_7.xsd'

Tags: eclipse, web.xml

When I try to auto generate the `web.xml` file while creating a Dynamic Web Project in the Eclipse Enterprise version it shows an error of type "Language Servers". It indicates to this element of the `web.xml` file as error:

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0"
>
```

[image: the error being]

> - There is '1' error in 'javaee_7.xsd'.
> - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is not xsd:schema.).

Comment: Sounds **exactly** like what was mentioned at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1107700/ and seemingly not reported to the LemMinX project.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: So how do I go on ahead with my web project? Do I use another (older)version of eclipse?

Comment: You should report this as an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/issues and see what they say.

Comment: This issue should be fixed with https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/pull/779 . Please wait for a new release of Wild Web Developer

Comment: This is fixed in the current snapshot build (2022-03-02)

Answer (score 11):

This is a bug in Eclipse which manifested since 2021-03.

It's broken down here: https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/issues/1042#issuecomment-859778034:

> Ok I can reproduce the issue with a fresh Eclipse IDE (the last). I can explain the problem but I don't know how to fix it (for the moment).
>
> When you have `"There is '1' error in 'jakartaee_9.xsd'"` error, you must open the XSD file (from the cache) and you should see 1 error and 1 warning:
>
> [image]
>
> There is a warning:
>
> ```
> schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.  jakartaee_9.xsd /lemminx-cache/https/jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee    line 52 Language Servers
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> which try to define xml:lang attribute inside xml.xsd file. But here the xml.xsd cannot be retrieved (the warning message) and you have the error:
>
> [image]
>
> It tries to download the XSD from `platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd` but platform is specific to Eclipse IDE. In other words when `http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd` must be resolved, it says that `platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd` is the location of XSD. I don't know who do that?
>
> I have the impression than LemMinx is configured to use XML catalog from WTP:
>
> [image]

While waiting for the Eclipse version with the fix (which is indeed not yet released at the time of writing), one work around is disable the LemMinx validation:

> @chris21k please note that you can disable LemMinx validation:
>
> [image]