# How to resolve the javaee_7.xsd error that occurs in the web.xml file?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I've seen one other user have this issue without a posted solution.

I'm still fairly new to the Enterprise Edition of Eclipse and have recently downloaded it to work on a web project. I added my apache Tomcat v10.0 Server without any issues and create a new Dynamic Web Project. Whenever I open the web.xml file I get this visual error and sometimes it pops up on its own. I've attempted to do this on my laptop and got the exact same error so I don't think it's an issue with my system. I would appreciate any help or ideas. Open to any extra details to help with resolving the issue.

[Image of Project Explorer and web.xml file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waQK4.png)

[Image of web.xml file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2jvN.png)

[Image of warning for "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQj4i.png)

[Image of error in 'javaee_7.xsd'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHKZt.png)

*EDIT:* ***Small solution workaround to anyone who's having the same issue.***

If you're ok with using a slightly older version of Eclipse EE, the version from 2020-09 works. Any newer versions run into the same issue. This version only goes up to Tomcat V9.

Just use eclipse installer -> [Top Right Hand] Select Dropdown Menu and Update -> Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java -> Should be able to change the Product Version to 2020-09.

Not a fix if you need to use the newer version of Eclipse EE.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271527/language-server-error-in-eclipse-web-xml-file : https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/issues/1042

Comment: Place images on this site. If the other one is unavailable your question can no longer be understood.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, dividing the long line "<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  ...." into several lines solves the error.

Comment: what the heck?!  Yeah, this did it.  Thanks!