# Eclipse web.xml "Referenced file contains errors"

Tags: eclipse, servlets, web.xml

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"
```

In this I'm getting error in this line

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/C:/Softwares/eclipse-jee-2023-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.2.600.v202307260543.jar!/dtdsAndSchemas/jakartaee_10.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details...

like this.

And the full Web.xml File is

Please help me to fix this issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
    <display-name>Abc</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDb58.png)

Comment: No, this is not my friend but we are facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. After lots of googling, disabling validations, trying to update Eclipse (as the XSD was contained in a Eclipse JAR file) ... the solution was simple (in retrospective). Just validate the web.xml file.
Right click on the file and find the **Validate** option.

[image]

After the validation has been completed the 'error' is gone.

[image]

I have done both **Project > Clean**, **Maven > Update** and restarted Eclipse (which for other 'solutions' took the error back) and the error is gone.